# Linking to http content from https page

Tags: javascript, html, https, widget

Our intranet is accessed via https.

I'm looking to add some external widgets like weather to it but they're all accessed via http so whenever the main page loads the user's browser informs the user that only secure content is displayed with the option to "Show All Content"

Is there anyway around this or is there a more elegant solution?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is warning that even though the page was loaded via https, which implies that it is secure, it is really not secure because of the http content. In most cases this is a good warning, the browser does not have a way to know what on the page is "important" so it must warn for anything like this. Example: the widget may be a weather widget where security is not important or a banking widget where security is important, the browser does not know.

The only fixes would be to load the page via http if security does not matter or use widgets that are loaded via https if security does matter.